# What comes after class name in braces? C++

Tags: c++, class, boost, syntax

I was debugging some app with boost usage and reached this point:

```
template<class R, class T, class A1, class A2, class A3 BOOST_MEM_FN_CLASS_F> 
class BOOST_MEM_FN_NAME(mf3)
{
public:

BOOST_MEM_FN_TYPEDEF(R (BOOST_MEM_FN_CC T::*F) (A1, A2, A3))
F f_;
 ...
some irrelevant code here..
```

What does this mean?? `BOOST_MEM_FN_NAME(mf3)` 
This is in `mem_fn_template.hpp`
I have not seen this syntax before. `class ClassName(something)`

Comment: Macro, of course.

Comment: its clearly a macro, why not find the macro and see what it does. Or tell the compiler / preproc to output the generated c++ code and see what got interested there

Comment: @pm100 Clearly it wasn't "clearly" a macro for the asker. A lot of people aren’t taught about macros in any detail because they’re clearly bad style, which unfortunately leads to questions like this.

Comment: @Daniel Macros aren't always "clearly" bad style. You're making the same mistake as the one you were pointing out ;).

Comment: @rubenvb No, they aren’t, but the people who don’t include anything about them in their courses might disagree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As its nameing style (ALL CAPS + underscores) suggests, I suppose it's a macro, which will be expanded to somethine else that doesn't look like `identifier(identifier)`. Then it all starts to make sense.

A quick Google search reveals the [original code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/boost/mem_fn.hpp) (at line 44):

```
#define BOOST_MEM_FN_NAME(X) inner_##X
```

Depending on whether other macros are defined, it has several definitions:

```
#define BOOST_MEM_FN_NAME(X) inner_##X##_cdecl
#define BOOST_MEM_FN_NAME(X) inner_##X##_stdcall
#define BOOST_MEM_FN_NAME(X) inner_##X##_fastcall
```

As a result, it will get expanded to various names

```
class inner_mf3;
class inner_mf3_cdecl;
class inner_mf3_stdcall;
class inner_mf3_fastcall;
```

Comment: It’s not a macro *definition*. The definition is where you say what the macro will expand to.

Comment: @DanielH Got it. Reworded.

Answer (score 2):

Its a macro..

```
#define BOOST_MEM_FN_NAME(X) inner_##X
```

it just appends `inner_` before whatever class name you are trying to put.

Answer (score 2):

It's a macro. It is defined in [mem_fn.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/boost/mem_fn.hpp) as:

```
#define BOOST_MEM_FN_NAME(X) inner_##X##_cdecl
```

Consequently,

```
class BOOST_MEM_FN_NAME(mf3) { ... };
```

translates to

```
class inner_mf3_cdecl { ... };
```